# User input after print

Tags: input, io, lua, output

I'm trying to make a simple lua program that converts Fahrenheit to Celsius and kelvin and I don't know how to put an input command on the same line as a print line. Here's what I mean.

I want the program to display:

```
Fahrenheit = "Here's the user input"
```

I know how to make it say

```
Fahrenheit =
"User input"
```

I'm still a novice.

This is my code so far:

```
print("Fahrenheit = ") f = io.read() c = (5/9)*(f-32) 
print("Celsius = "..c) k = c + 273 print("Kelvin = "..k)
```

Comment: I was trying to make the program print out "Fahrenheit =" and it will allow you to enter in a number right after the equals sign. I managed to get it working.

Comment: I understand your question now :), clearly I lack reading comprehension.

Answer (score 4):

Look into `io.write()` and `io.read()`. For instance, you could say:

```
io.write("Fahrenheit = ")
```

The write command writes output to the screen buffer, but doesn't add a newline. Similarly, `read` checks the latest input, and returns it.

For reference, I suggest [this link](http://www.lua.org/pil/21.1.html) from the tutorial.

Comment: I don't understand exactly how I would use it and I have come across that page earlier. Could you by any chance give me an example? If it helps, here is my code so far.

Comment: print("Fahrenheit = ")
f = io.read()
c = (5/9)*(f-32)
print("Celsius = "..c)
k = c + 273
print("Kelvin = "..k)

Comment: Simply change `print` to `io.write`, but be sure to  remember your newline (`\n`) character; that will resolve formatting issues.

Comment: io.write("Fahrenheit = ")
f = io.read()
c = (5/9)*(f-32)
print("Celsius = "..c)
k = c + 273
print("Kelvin = "..k)